# Converting button events etc to ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Given an asp.net webform page which does something like

asp.net

```
 <asp:textbox id="txtA" runat="server" />
 <asp:textbox id="txtB" runat="server" />
 <asp:button id="btnAddTogether" runat="server" text="Go" onclick="btn_Click"/>

 <asp:textbox id="txtResult" runat="server" />
```

code behind

```
protected void btn_Click(...)
{
    txtResult.Text = txtA.Text + txtB.Text;
}
```

How would I convert this to ASP.NET MVC. It's a pretty trivial example, but I'm not sure about how to change my way of thinking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's really no direct conversion.

Theoretically, that button would be submitting a Model (via a `<form>` tag) to a Controller for an Update Action. The string manipulation would then happen inside of your Controller code.

Your example would become something like:

```
<% using Html.BeginForm("Update", "Home") { %>
    <%= Html.TextBox("txtA") %>
    <%= Html.TextBox("txtB") %>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
<% } %
```

And then your controller would have:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Update(string txtA, string txtB)
    {
        ViewData["result"] = txtA + txtB;
    }
}
```

Comment: Would you be able to give me an example to get started with please.

Comment: Thanks Justin. As @Anero mentions, this is a hacky way but it will work. Am already converting to ViewData way now :)

Comment: @Sophie88: Using ViewData is bad approach. You should stay away from non strongly types solutions. Using view model is the best way.

Comment: @Sophie88 LukLed is right, you should try to work towards using a ViewModel (which is strongly typed, unlike the ViewData collection).

Answer (score 6):

I'd also recommend you to read the MVC tutorials, but for this particular case you would do something like the following.

In the .aspx (let's assume it's called *ViewA*):

```
<% using(Html.BeginForm("Concatenate"))
{ %>
    <%= Html.TextBox("txtA") %>
    <%= Html.TextBox("txtB") %>
    <input type="submit" value="Go" />
<% } %>

<%= Html.TextBox("txtResult")%>
```

In the Controller for that View you'll need an action:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult Concatenate(string txtA, string txtB)
    {
        this.ViewData["txtResult"] = txtA + txtB;
        return this.View("ViewA");
    }
```

Note that **this isn't the recommended way**, instead of using the ViewData dictionary, you sould use a specific ViewModel class with all the data for the particular view.

Comment: +1 for the addendum - there is a fundamental mental shift between MVC and ASP.NET "classic", which goes all the way back to the basic plumbing and concepts.  Yes, you can do stuff the "old" way, but it really gets hacky, fast.

Comment: @Anero - thanks. This is a great solution, but I'll be doing it best-practice :)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a `Click` handler, you make a `<form>` tag that submits to an Action.
The action can then perform its logic and return a view that displays the result.

Answer (score 1):

There is such a method, too.

```
  [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, 
                  AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
  public class SubmitCommandAttribute : ActionMethodSelectorAttribute
  {
    private string _submitName;
    private string _submitValue;
    private static readonly AcceptVerbsAttribute _innerAttribute = 
                                 new AcceptVerbsAttribute(HttpVerbs.Post);

    public SubmitCommandAttribute(string name) : this(name, string.Empty) { }
        public SubmitCommandAttribute(string name, string value)
    {
          _submitName = name;
          _submitValue = value;
    }

    public override bool IsValidForRequest(ControllerContext controllerContext, 
                                           MethodInfo methodInfo)
    {
      if (!_innerAttribute.IsValidForRequest(controllerContext, methodInfo))
        return false;

      // Form Value
      var submitted = controllerContext.RequestContext
                                       .HttpContext
                                       .Request.Form[_submitName];
      return string.IsNullOrEmpty(_submitValue)
               ? !string.IsNullOrEmpty(submitted)
               : string.Equals(submitted, _submitValue, 
                               StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
    }
  }
```

Sample controller code.

```
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

    [ActionName("Different")]
    [SubmitCommand("DoSave")]
    public ActionResult DifferentSave()
    {
      TempData["message"] = "saved! - defferent";
      return View("Index");
    }

    [ActionName("Different")]
    [SubmitCommand("DoDelete")]
    public ActionResult DifferentDelete()
    {
      TempData["message"] = "deleted! - defferent";
      return View("Index");
    }

    [ActionName("Same")]
    [SubmitCommand("DoSubmit","Save")]
    public ActionResult SameSave()
    {
      TempData["message"] = "saved! - same";
      return View("Index");
    }

    [ActionName("Same")]
    [SubmitCommand("DoSubmit","Delete")]
    public ActionResult SameDelete()
    {
      TempData["message"] = "deleted! - same";
      return View("Index");
    }
  }
```

and view.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1><%= TempData["message"] ?? "Click some button" %></h1>

  <h2>Different sumit name(ignore value).</h2>    
  <% using (Html.BeginForm("Different", "Home")) { %>
    <input type="submit" name="DoSave" value="Save" /><br />
    <input type="submit" name="DoDelete" value="Delete" />
    <% } %>

  <h2>same submit name and different value.</h2>    
  <% using (Html.BeginForm("Same","Home")) { %>
    <input type="submit" name="DoSubmit" value="Save" /><br />
    <input type="submit" name="DoSubmit" value="Delete" />
    <% } %>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope this code.

Answer (score 1):

**You don't have to create any views, like others suggested. You don't have to wrap it up into form, because these inputs will be propably part of bigger form.**

When you start using ASP.NET MVC, you have to learn JavaScript/jQuery. It can replace a lot of functions that were solved by using postback mechanism in WebForms.

This example can be easily solved on client side or server side:

```
<form action="" method="post">
<%= Html.TextBox("txtA") %>
<%= Html.TextBox("txtB") %>
<button id="btClientSideAdd" onclick="$('#txtResult').val($('#txtA').val() + $('#txtB').val()); return false;">
    Add on client</button>
<button id="btServerSideAdd" onclick="$.post('Home/Add', { a: $('#txtA').val(), b: $('#txtB').val()  }, function(data) { $('#txtResult').val(data) }); return false;">
    Add on server</button>
<%= Html.TextBox("txtResult") %>
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Additional code for server side:

```
public JsonResult Add(string txtA, string txtB)
{
    return Json(txtA + txtB);
}
```

This code adds on client side:

```
$('#txtResult').val($('#txtA').val() + $('#txtB').val());
```

You can also pass values to server:

```
$.post(
  'Home/Add', //Action to execute
  { a: $('#txtA').val(), b: $('#txtB').val()  }, //input values
  function(data) { $('#txtResult').val(data) } //what to do with result
);
```

To do it on client side, you have to use [jQuery.post()/jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). Read about using partial view and JsonResults.

Comment: Although jQuery is included with MVC, there is no requirement to use it.  While it works for this trivial example, it's probably not good advice long-term or for more complex business logic.

Comment: @GalacticCowboy: Sorry, but I don't agree. jQuery/AJAX is basic tool when you want to update part of the page. Do you want to post whole page to update one field? This is crazy. There is no requirement to use jQuery, but it is not wise not to.

Comment: As I said, "While it works for this trivial example..." - I think you stated precisely what I was trying to say.  The OP is a rather trivial example, so yes in that scenario jQuery makes perfect sense.  As a larger example of how to handle form submissions, etc., not so much.

Comment: @GalacticCowboy: But it is not form submission. If it was form submission, there would be other postback code. There is absolutely no submission code (there is no further processing, validation, saving to database etc.). She wants to fill some parts of the form and continue work on it.

Comment: She is asking about the "MVC Way" - the mental shift in MVC vs. ASP.NET.  As stated in the OP, it is a simple, contrived example that demonstrates submitting a form in ASP.NET, doing *something* server-side and returning a response to the client.  You are correct that the *stated* problem is best solved without posting back to the server.  What I am trying to say is that the *stated* problem is only a proxy for the *real* problem, how did form processing change from ASP.NET to MVC?

Answer (score 0):

Better if you check MVC tutorials here. http://www.asp.net/learn/mvc/.

And if you are really looking for changing a current application to MVC then you should see [this](http://www.asp.net/learn/mvc-videos/video-8144.aspx) video first.